# Why doesn't my discord bot go online without an error or anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So basically, I've tried to fix this issue for hours and hours without success. This is what happens when I try to launch the bot:

https://gyazo.com/3a941b4372c88be07c76c5b004327f71

I've checked that the main is right and that everything is right like the json files and the actual code.

bot.js ->

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);

  bot.user.setActivity("Tickets", {type: "WATCHING"});

});

bot.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);

  if(cmd === `${prefix}new`){

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Ticket created")
  .setDescription("Ticket #ticket- has been created successfully.")
  .setColor("#15f153")
  .setFooter("chefren#9582 | 2019")


    return message.channel.send(embed);

}


    if(cmd === `${prefix}ticketcreation`){

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Ticket")
    .setDescription("Do you require help or support? React with :white_check_mark: ")
    .setColor("#15f153")
    .setFooter("dl121#9582 | 2019")

      msg = await message.channel.send(embed);

      await msg.react('✅')

      message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
        }


});

bot.login(botconfig.token);
    }
  })
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A bot",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "andrew",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cjs": "0.0.11",
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "node.js": "0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

There was this error message before that I fixed:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Discord Bots\Bot\bot,js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Why is the `.on("ready"` callback function defined as `async`? It's not doing anything with promises, so try removing that keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I removed it and thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, it looks like there's a bit of a problem with your curly braces. The `bot.login({...})` call was actually inside of the `bot.on('message'` handler. Obviously you won't receive messages without first logging in, so that's probably what's going on.

I re-indented your code and added the necessary curly braces and parentheses to make the `bot.login` call run at the end of the script, outside of any handler functions.

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);

  bot.user.setActivity("Tickets", {type: "WATCHING"});

});

bot.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);

  if (cmd === `${prefix}new`) {

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Ticket created")
    .setDescription("Ticket #ticket- has been created successfully.")
    .setColor("#15f153")
    .setFooter("chefren#9582 | 2019")

    return message.channel.send(embed);

  }


  if (cmd === `${prefix}ticketcreation`) {

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Ticket")
    .setDescription("Do you require help or support? React with :white_check_mark: ")
    .setColor("#15f153")
    .setFooter("dl121#9582 | 2019")

    let msg = await message.channel.send(embed);

    await msg.react('✅')

    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })'
    .then(collected => {
      const reaction = collected.first();

      if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
      }
    });
  }
});

// *** CHANGES WERE MADE ABOVE HERE ***

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Comment: Okay, it worked now. Thanks. I really appreciate your help.